# how to move or drag items between two divs or selectboxes by using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to move the list items or selectbox items between the divs or selectboxes..
i am unable to how to know to use the jquery plugins and how to implement..
would you please help me.... if i download one plugin how to make it use in my application...
Help me plz..

Thank you

Comment: I'm really not finding it clear what you need to do! sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mihir

I got one more good link from google , see if it is useful to you

```
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/
```

this is also very good as others suggested

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/
```

Comment: Thank you so much... how to under stand the code would tell me?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable Interactions is what you want

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/